# JS Countdown Timer Stoping at Zero

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my countdown timer to stop at zero and display done. For some reason I can't get it to stop at 0:00.

```
var timer = 10;
var secondsRemaining;
var interval = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function convertSeconds(timer) {
  var min = Math.floor(timer / 60);
  var sec = timer - min * 60;

  //add a leading zero (as a string value) if seconds less than 10
  if (sec < 10) {
    sec = "0" + sec;
  }
  return min + ":" + sec;
}

//
function myTimer() {
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = convertSeconds(timer);
  timer--;
  if (timer <= 0) clearInterval(interval);
}
```

https://codepen.io/powershell19/pen/vYNbeZy

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, just need to **edit the if condition**

```
var timer = 10;
var secondsRemaining;
var interval = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function convertSeconds(timer) {
    var min = Math.floor(timer / 60);
    var sec = timer - min * 60;

    //add a leading zero (as a string value) if seconds less than 10
    if (sec < 10) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }
    return min + ":" + sec;
}

//
function myTimer() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = convertSeconds(timer);
    timer--;
    if (timer < 0) clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following statement from :

```
if (timer <= 0) clearInterval(interval);
```

to

```
if (timer < 0) clearInterval(interval);
```

Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I changed this part of your code.

```
function myTimer() {
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = convertSeconds(timer);
  timer--;
  if (timer <= 0) clearInterval(interval);
}
```

to

```
function myTimer() {
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = convertSeconds(timer);
  if (timer-- <= 0) clearInterval(interval);
}
```

to check the time if it is zero then it will still do the last interval of 0 second and then it decrements afterward.

Answer (score 0):

I know, there are quite a few answers here already, but maybe this one is still of interest to someone. I have changed the code slightly by putting the former global variables into the local scope of the `myTimer()` function. Now separate independent timers can be started using this new `myTimer()` function.

"Write less, do more"

```js
myTimer('timer',10,1000);
myTimer('t2',20,600);

function myTimer(domId,time,intv){
 var trgt=document.getElementById(domId),
   timer=time,
   self=setInterval(function(){
     trgt.innerHTML=Math.floor (timer / 60)+':'+(''+timer%60).padStart(2,'0');
     if (!timer--) clearInterval(self);
   },intv);
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
<div id="t2"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var timer = 10;
var secondsRemaining;
var interval = setInterval(myTimer,1000);

function convertSeconds(timer)
{
var min = Math.floor (timer / 60);
var sec = timer - (min * 60);

//add a leading zero (as a string value) if seconds less than 10
if (sec < 10) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }
return min + ':' + sec;
}

//
function myTimer()                         
{
const showtimer=document.getElementById("timer")
showtimer.innerHTML = convertSeconds(timer);
timer--; 
if (timer < 0){                        
  clearInterval(interval);
  showtimer.innerHTML='Done'
}
}
```