# JS - it dosen't count zero second in a timer

Tags: javascript, timer

```js
let second = 2 // Make more realistic instead of 60
let minute = 1
let mytimer = setInterval(function(){
  let timer = second--
  console.log(minute + ':' + timer)
  if(second==0){
    second = 59
    minute--
  }
  if(minute==0){
    clearInterval(mytimer);
  }
},10)
```

As you can see, it's quite simple code, but there is a weird bug in there. my timer doesn't count second 0. When the timer gonna end, it'll stop at 0:01. it works perfectly by itself, but when it reaches 1:00 or 0:00 it entirely ignores 0 and jumps from 1:01 to 0:59.
I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62186864/js-countdown-timer-stoping-at-zero), but it doesn't work too.
what do I suppose to do now?
(btw my previous questions weren't good enough, and I hope I could've to reach a better explanation this time)

Comment: Try tracing your code on paper and see what happens

Comment: FYI setInterval is not accurate and your code is not counting down seconds.

Comment: You are cancelling the timer when minute is zero, not when minute and second is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is stopping when min is 0, not when min and sec is zero. You need to change up your logic to account for that.

```js
let second = 0;
let minute = 2;

let mytimer = setInterval(function() {
  second--;
  if (second === 0 && minute === 0) {
    clearInterval(mytimer);
  } else if (second < 0) {
    second = 60 + second;
    minute--;
  }

  console.log(minute + ':' + second.toString().padStart(2, '0'))

}, 1000)
```

Now setInterval is NOT accurate. It will float. So it is better to use the a timestamp and get the difference.

```js
function msToTime(ms) {
  const seconds = Math.floor((ms / 1000) % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const minutes = Math.floor((ms / (1000 * 60)) % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  
  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

const countDownTime = (outElem, ms) => {
  const endTS = Date.now() + ms;
  let timer;
  
  const display = text => outElem.textContent = text;

  const countDown = () => {
    const diff = endTS - Date.now();
    if (diff < 0) {
      display("00:00");
      window.clearTimeout(timer);
      return;
    }

    const ts = msToTime(diff);
    display(ts);
  };

  countDown();
  window.setInterval(countDown, 10);

};

countDownTime(document.querySelector('#out'), 2*60*1000);
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that your function is executed every 10 milliseconds, so when the timer reaches 1:00, it will skip the second zero and immediately jump to 0:59. To fix this 'issue', you can change the interval time from 10 milliseconds to 1000 milliseconds so it will display the 1:00 correctly.
To do that, you have to replace the 10 at the end.

Comment: This answer is wrong and the solution doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, it dosen't work....

Answer (score -2):

This one is giving me the answer which you are looking for,

```js
let second = 59 // Make more realistic instead of 60
let minute = 1
let mytimer = setInterval(function(){
  let timer = second--
  console.log(minute + ':' + timer)
  if(second<0){
    second = 59
    minute--
  }
  if(minute==0){
    clearInterval(mytimer);
  }
},10)
```